# "In extensive grounds" vs. "on extensive grounds"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

If there is a large house, can I say either of the following?

> - The house stands **in** extensive grounds.
> - The house stands **on** extensive grounds.

Which one makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only *The house stands in extensive grounds.* makes sense, because the extensive grounds (presumably) surround the house. You enter the extensive grounds, and inside you find the house.

[Confirmed by Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stands%20on%20extensive%20grounds,stands%20in%20extensive%20grounds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

You might come across *["standing on extensive grounds"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww&ei=OkJaUqikHsSHrgesjYGIAw&ved=0CBYQ1S4#hl=en&q=%22standing%20on%20extensive%20grounds%22&safe=off)* in estate agency blurb or perhaps in an architectural context, but not in normal speech. They do this to emphasise that you are buying yourself extensive grounds, and there is also a house on the land you are buying.

Comment: For "lot of land" read "*plot* of land" in British English. "A lot of land" could be referring to the *amount* of land (as in "a lot of money"), and not to the *parcel* or *plot* of land.

Comment: I am British... and no, I didn't mean to say "a plot of land" and get it wrong. I meant to say "a lot of land" because "extensive" means "a lot". "Extensive grounds" means "a lot of land", right?

Comment: Apologies - but there's no indication of your nationality in your profile, and I genuinely assumed you mean what I wrote. (In retrospect, your use of "estate agent" tends to suggest BrE!)  We also don't know whether OP speaks BrE or AmE, so my point still applies in reverse. "A lot of land" is ambiguous between BrE & AmE - perhaps "lots of land" or "a large amount of land"?

Comment: Aaaaah... I see what you are getting at now. Americans buy lots. I missed that one! I don't put my nationality (or qualifications or anything else...) on my profile because I think my answers should stand or fall on their own merit. Some of this is due to spending the past 10 years living in SEA, and meeting at lot of British expats who seem to think that being native speakers or having British degrees makes them instant language experts. I don't want to be one of that crowd.